# TToolBar: Customize the BRIGHTNESS of the "gray-out" effect when a button is disabled?

Tags: delphi, toolbar, delphi-10.1-berlin

In a Delphi 10.1.2 project, I have a `TToolBar` with enabled buttons on a VCL form:

[image]

When I disable the buttons then the buttons have a dark gray color:

[image]

This dark gray color is too dark for my purpose, I need a much lighter gray color when the buttons are disabled.

I know that `TToolBar` has a `DisabledImages` property where I can assign a custom imagelist with custom disabled images; but I need to make the button images look disabled without using the `DisabledImages` property at design-time (i.e. without having to manually create imagelists for the disabled images at design-time) by just using only the "gray-out" effect when the buttons are disabled.

So how can I customize the BRIGHTNESS of the "gray-out" effect when a button is disabled?

Here is the source code of the project:

[Unit2.pas](https://pastebin.com/5YaGUa5Q)

[Unit2.dfm](https://pastebin.com/te216ha9)

[CustomizeDisabledColors.dpr](https://pastebin.com/TNaAvkF6)

Comment: I have found an excellent solution here: http://developers-club.com/posts/160455/

Comment: Well, originally you said: *but I need to make the button images look disabled without using the `DisabledImages` property by just using only the "gray-out" effect when the buttons are disabled*. The solution you then claim to be excellent does exactly that, uses `DisabledImages`. I know you changed the question to fit the answer you found, but this is a typical example of an xy question, asking for how to do x, thinking that is the solution, while the actual problem is y. Anyway I agree that the quality of the images is much better than the standard disabled images and made a note for myself